# blueimp thumbnails and rewritten url, different in FF and Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, json, blueimp

I want to use blueimp file upload on my site.
The url is rewritten with params and sites build with header and content files.

Pictures are stored in folders (with thumbnail folder inside); foldername is given over session ($_SESSION['post']['folder']).
Script works fine if folder is empty, but if there are pictures inside no thumbnails will be created and the famous error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data is show (but picture is online and can be deleted).
In firefox script works, in chrome always SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and no pictures ....

If i change the upload url, no pictures are show and/or upload or delete function do not work....

i tried with changing in index.php and in uploadhandler...

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/../../../photo/'.$_SESSION['post']['folder'].'/',

'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/../../../photo/'.$_SESSION['post']['folder'].'',
```

The folder for pictures is outside the folder of script, pictures are in photo and script is in picture.

How can i get the script to work in chrome and ff with thumbnails? I think the problem is the rewritten url, so that the script call included files wrong...